# Embedding ASPX in ASP page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have an ASPX based component which I'd need to inlude into a plain ASP based
script. Scenario is, that I'm working within an LMS system (Angel to be exact)
and I wan't to create a new nugget within that framework. An Angel nugget is 
pretty much what a portlet is in the Java world.

Now, the nugget spec. states that my starting point has to be a file called 
default.asp. What I'd like to do is:

- read relevant data from ASP session
- pass data to ASPX component
- have ASPX do it's job and display the results

My problem is that I fail to run / display my ASPX component without
using an iframe, which I want to avoid since that crushes the layout /
design of my nugget.

Is there a way to get this done properly or do I have to rewrite my 
component in ASP to get this going?

*Note:* the component performs 
web service queries and such and I'd like to avoid rewriting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you grab the .aspx content from the .asp page using the MSXML object?

```
url = "http://www.yoururl.com/YourPage.aspx?relevantData=YourRelevantData"
```

Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.SERVERXMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET",url,False
xml.send
html = xml.ResponseText
Set xml = Nothing

Response.Write(html)